# sass variable gets overridden when compiled into one file

Tags: sass

I have a setup with sass where I need a way to store a value without it getting overridden when I minify all my css together.

I have a template scss file that styles a specific bunch of tags that have class selectors.
Then I have a body id selector on each html page. Each html page has its own unique scss file.
I need a way to assign the unique body id selector to a variable so it can be used to append the unique page id to the start of every class in the template scss file . Example:

**template.scss**

```
    $basePageID: "";

    #{$basePageID} .myclass{

    }
   #{$basePageID} .myclass2{

    }
```

Now in my html specific scss files I have this setup.

```
**homepage.scss**

    @import "template.scss";
    $basePageID: "#home";

    #{$basePageID} .myclass{

    }

**contact.scss**
    @import "template.scss";
    $basePageID: "#contact";

    #{$basePageID} .myclass{

    }
```

Ok so hopefully you can see what I'm trying to do here. The problem is when all my css files are minified the $basePageID variable will get set to whatever is the last css file to be added. I need a way to be able to pass template the unique page id for each scss file even when all files are combined into one css file. Not sure how I can do that in scss

Comment: How do you minify/combine your CSS files?

Answer (score 0):

Cant you just do this...

template.scss:

```
#{$basePageID} .myclass{

}
#{$basePageID} .myclass2{

}
```

homepage.scss:

```
$basePageID: "#home";
@import "template.scss";

#{$basePageID} .myclass{

}
```

To me it looked like you where overwriting the basePageID at the wrong times.